# Programmatically add a taxonomy term as entity reference in a custom entity

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, entities

I'm really struggling to add a taxonomy_term as an entity reference to a custom entity I've created programmatically.

Here is my configuration based on BaseFieldDefinition (the name of the vocabulary is "specialite":

```
$fields['speciality_field'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ->setLabel(t('speciality'))
  ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
  ->setSetting('target_type', 'taxonomy_term')
  >setSetting('handler_settings', ['target_bundles' => ['specialite' => 'specialite']])
  ->setSetting('handler', 'default')
  ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
    'label' => 'hidden',
    'type' => 'author',
    'weight' => 0,
  ))
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
    'weight' => 5,
    'settings' => array(
      'match_operator' => 'CONTAINS',
      'size' => '10',
      'autocomplete_type' => 'tags',
      'placeholder' => '',
    ),
  ))
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

This piece of code doesn't work, would you please help to find what I am missing, or redirect me to a good documentation explaining different values for handler_settings

Thank you so much.

Comment: include this in     'settings' => [
        'target_type' => 'taxonomy_term',
      ],

Comment: already done , as mentionned in my question:->setSetting('target_type', 'taxonomy_term')

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well thank you, the answer of 4k4 was very useful.
My problem was that for my field I wanted to reference to a taxonomy term, I had already created it and dropped it directly in the database.
It's seems no to be the right way to do this, so I was having such trouble recreating it.
So unisntalled my module (after removing all the data) , and reinstalled it , and then this piece of code worked perfectly to have a reference to a taxonomy term:

```
$fields['speciality'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ->setSetting('target_type', 'taxonomy_term')
  ->setSetting('handler', 'default:taxonomy_term')
  ->setSetting('handler_settings', 
      array(
    'target_bundles' => array(
     'specialite' => 'specialite'
    )))
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
    'label' => 'hidden',
    'type' => 'author',
    'weight' => 0,
  ))
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
    'weight' => 3,
    'settings' => array(
      'match_operator' => 'CONTAINS',
      'size' => '10',
      'autocomplete_type' => 'tags',
      'placeholder' => '',
    ),
  ))
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

PS: specialite is my the name of my vocabulary

Answer (score 3):

You can use the handler settings drupal generates, when you add a taxonomy field in ui:

```
settings:
  handler: 'default:taxonomy_term'
  handler_settings:
    target_bundles:
      tags: tags
    sort:
      field: _none
    auto_create: false
```

This is the config of tags in article, so you need to swap tags with your vocabulary.

Comment: I'll try this. But please where do you find this settings generated in drupal ui?

Comment: This is stored in config. Use drush for example: `drush cedit field.field.node.article.field_tags`, or the config export options in ui.

Comment: I doesn't solve my problem, here my modification:   ->setSetting('handler', 'default:taxonomy_term')
      ->setSetting('handler_settings', 
          array(
        'target_bundles' => array(
         'specialite' => 'specialite'
       )))